# jQuery Change input css style with two dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I have two dropdowns and one input field, in the input field is a text. In the first dropdown I have fonts: Arial, Impact... and in the second field I have color: red, blue...

All I want is when I choose the font and the color to change the text in the input field. For now font is changed and I'm trying to figure it out how to change color too.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".product-options dd select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    jQuery(".product-options dd select option:selected").each(function() {
      str += jQuery(this).text();
    });
    jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").css('font-family', str);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="product-options-wrapper" class="product-options">
  <dd>
    <div class="input-box">
      <select id="select_9" class="product-custom-option form-control" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" title="" name="options[9]">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option price="0" value="42867">standard skrifttype</option>
        <option price="0" value="36">Arial</option>
        <option price="0" value="37">Lato</option>
        <option price="0" value="42871">Impact</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </dd>

  <dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
      <select id="select_6022" class="product-custom-option form-control" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" title="" name="options[6022]">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option price="0" value="42958">red</option>
        <option price="0" value="42957">blue</option>
        <option price="0" value="42959">green</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <div class="input-box">
      <ul id="options-6022-list" class="options-list">
        <li>
    <input id="options_6022" class="radio product-custom-option" type="radio" checked="checked" value="" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[6022]">
    <span class="label">
    <label for="options_6022">None</label>
    </span>
        </li>
        <li>
    <input id="options_6022_2" class="radio product-custom-option" type="radio" price="0" value="42959" name="options[6022]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
    <span class="label">
    <label for="options_6022_2">black </label>
    </span>
        </li>
        <li>
    <input id="options_6022_3" class="radio product-custom-option" type="radio" price="0" value="42958" name="options[6022]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
    <span class="label">
    <label for="options_6022_3">blue </label>
    </span>
        </li>
        <li>
    <input id="options_6022_4" class="radio product-custom-option" type="radio" price="0" value="42957" name="options[6022]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
    <span class="label">
    <label for="options_6022_4">red </label>
    </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </dd>

  <dd>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input id="options_11_text mirror" class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-25 product-custom-option form-control" type="text" value="" name="options[11]" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="font-family: -- Please Select --blå;">
      <p class="note">Maximum number of characters:<strong>25</strong>
      </p>
    </div>
  </dd>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I try to use the code like this but I don't know what is wrong:

```
jQuery('select.change-color').change(function () {
    jQuery('.product-options input.input-text').css('font-family', jQuery('option:selected', this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the font dropdown, you can use:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".product-options dd select").change(function() {
    var str = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").css("font-family", str);
  });
});
```

For the color radio buttons, use:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".product-options dd :radio").click(function() {
    var str = $(this).next().find("label").text();
    jQuery(".product-options dd input.input-text").css("color", str);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for your answer, unfortunately I have no way to identify with is first dropdown and second, is created automatically in the backend of the store, this dropdown are product options in Magento.

Comment: Doesn't the backend know whether it's listing colors or fonts when it's creating the dropdowns? It should be able to put the appropriate value into the `<select>`.

Comment: no in the backend exist a button, with this button you can add fields: inputbox, textarea, dropdown, and all this are build one by one in admin, only thing that is change there is the ID but this is not help us anymore.

Comment: Then I don't know how your Javascript can possibly know which CSS style should be changed with each dropdown. There has to be some way for it to know what the dropdown is for.

Comment: please take a look here, this is the file from where is create that select: http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml.source.html

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to get help from someone who knows Magento. I don't know it.

Comment: All I can do is to add a class or ID to the input field

Comment: and other idea is to change the color dropdown in checkbox, what do you think this will help us?

Comment: How will that help if the admin is creating these things dynamically? How does it know the checkbox is for color and the dropdown is for font? What stops him from using a checkbox for font, too?

Comment: I can make a rule for this, exactly like this: for example for fonts to use dropdown and for colors to use checkbox, but we can solve this in jquery?

Comment: You should use radio buttons, not checkboxes, so they can only check one of them. Then you can use `$(".product-options dd select").change()` and the code there will set the font, and `$(".product-options dd :radio").change()` to set the color.

Comment: You said you can add a class to the input field. Couldn't you use `$(".fontselect")` and `$(".colorselect")` for the different dropdowns?

Comment: please take a look now, I edit my code, I add the radio buttons

Comment: I can add a class at the text input field, is in the very bottom of the code, i add it already is "mirror" <input id="options_11_text mirror"

Comment: I've changed my answer to show how to do different things for the select and radio buttons. But if you have more inputs, you'll run out of different types, so this isn't a very general solution.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand, so is not exist a solution?

Comment: In general, you need some way to know what each input element is for. Either you hard-code the IDs into your Javascript, or you put something in the element that the Javascript uses.

Comment: I understand, anyway I think you help me a lot, the solution is temorary work :) thank you very much

Comment: Hi Barmar, do you have one minute? I solve and I find a solution to add a class to each dropdown

Comment: now i have in that input something like this <div class="input-box colorclass"> and for font <div class="input-box fontclass"> you tell me a solution yestarday can you put it here again please?

Comment: Just change the selectors above to `$(".fontclass")` and `$(".colorclass")`

Comment: yes but here are two jquery functions, you put this yesterday in only one

Comment: If you have any idea what you're doing, you should be able to adapt my answer to your needs. If you can't, you're not cut out for this. I'm not trying to be mean, but you really can't expect to be spoon fed every little detail, you need to learn how things work and figure it out on your own.